# How to split string in different string occurrences?

Tags: java

I have a String. I want to split string in multiple string occurrences. 
Ex:

```
String str= "A809C0034F3A04C9024F80A905C5034F6008AA08C2024F4ACB024F5AFFFF";
```

**A8**09C0034F3A04C9024F80**A9**05C5034F6008**AA**08C2024F4ACB024F5AFFFF

I want split string at A8 , A9 and AA.
can you please provide information about this.

Comment: So you want to get a few *substrings* from the longer string?

Comment: Well, there is a `split` method in `String` class that takes a regex to split a String. Then there is this `|` operator

Comment: Use `.split()` and provide a regex that matches on the three values.

Comment: Do you need to keep the A8 etc

Comment: What is your expected output ? share more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well You have to use `split()` and accept multiple matches .

```
String str= "A809C0034F3A04C9024F80A905C5034F6008AA08C2024F4ACB024F5AFFFF";
String[] splits = str.split("A8|A9|AA");

for(String st:splits){
    System.out.println(st);
}
```

output:

```
09C0034F3A04C9024F80
05C5034F6008
08C2024F4ACB024F5AFFFF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str= "A809C0034F3A04C9024F80A905C5034F6008AA08C2024F4ACB024F5AFFFF";

    String[] s = str.split("A[8|9|A]");

    for(String st:s){
        System.out.println(st);
    }
```

Comment: How do you keep the delimeter?

Comment: For the above specific use case I can only find delimiter as `A{alphanumeric}0`